# How to fix the extending line-height when using a "bottom-right quotation mark"?

Tags: html, css

Here is the HTML code:

```css
div {font-size:1.5em}
div b {font-size:2em}
div {width:360px; border:1px solid red}
```

```html
<div><b>“</b>The real test is not whether you avoid this failure, because you won't. It's whether you let it harden or shame you into inaction, or whether you learn from it; whether you choose to persevere.<b>„</b></div>


<div><b>“</b> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog... 
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog... 
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.. 
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.. 
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
 <b>„</b></div>
```

The last line will have a higher height which looks quite weird.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Try to use :last-child CSS

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`<blockquote>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blockquote) for blockquotes. Or [`<q>` for short quotes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/q). Don't add the quotation marks with markup, add them via CSS.

```css
blockquote {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  width: 360px;
  border: 1px solid red
}

blockquote::before {
 content: "“";
}

blockquote::after {
  content: "„";
}
```

```html
<blockquote>The real test is not whether you avoid this failure, because you won't. It's whether you let it harden or shame you into inaction, or whether you learn from it; whether you choose to persevere.</blockquote>


<blockquote> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog... The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog... The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.. The quick brown fox
  jumps over the lazy dog.
</blockquote>
```

Comment: Good idea to improve the semantic HTML, but if you set the before and after pseudo  content as `font-size:2em`, the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding line-height: 0; to the element

```css
div {font-size:1.5em}
div b {font-size:2em}
div {width:360px; border:1px solid red}
.myspace {line-height: 0}
```

```html
<div><b>“</b>The real test is not whether you avoid this failure, because you won't. It's whether you let it harden or shame you into inaction, or whether you learn from it; whether you choose to persevere.<b class = "myspace">„</b></div>


<div><b>“</b> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog... 
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog... 
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.. 
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.. 
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
 <b class = "myspace">„</b></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `last-child` CSS to `b` tag

```css
div {font-size:1.5em}
div b {font-size:2em}
div {width:360px; border:1px solid red}
div b:last-child {
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div><b>“</b>The real test is not whether you avoid this failure, because you won't. It's whether you let it harden or shame you into inaction, or whether you learn from it; whether you choose to persevere.<b>„</b></div>


<div><b>“</b> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog... 
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog... 
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.. 
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog..
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
 <b>„</b></div>
```